# How to load 3D objects at runtime in Augmented Reality using Kudan AR (Unity 3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, kudan

I am currently developing an augmented reality application with Kudan AR. I want to have a list of buttons (which I already did) where in when a specific button is clicked, a specific 3D object will appear too in the camera. I tried a few times but the object being showed is 2D and it just follows the camera (Markerless AR) which is wrong. I wonder if anyone here knows the answer to my question. It would be very helpful for me. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do marker tracking then (and not markerless)?

If you are looking to hardcode a few buttons the make 3D objects appear on a marker this is one possible implementation.

Attach your 3D objects to the Marker Driver (Driver->Marker). You can find examples in the sample scenes. Set all the models to be inactive. Create your UI buttons. Set the onClick for each button to activate the respective 3D model and set the others to inactive. Hope that helps!